# M300 - How to pick a lens and take a picture? SDK IOS

Tags: ios, dji-sdk

I'm trying to take pictures with the M300 RTK using the iOS SDK. I'm adapting a working Mavic 2 Pro app but impossible to make it work with the M300 RTK with H20.

I've tried the following code :

```swift
camera?.setFlatMode(DJIFlatCameraMode.photoSingle, withCompletion: { (e:Error?) in
   // some error handling                
   // take the photo
   camera?.startShootPhoto(completion: { (error:Error?) in
      // other error handling
   })
})
```

This code doesn't send any error but the drone doesn't take any picture. I've managed to take pictures using `PhotoInterval` twice but now setting the `TimeIntervalSetting` returns `DJI SDK has come across unknown error code(217). Please update SDK or contact DJI Developer Relations to know more information on this error`.

And even when I was taking pictures, I was unable to select which lens to use (H20 has two lenses : zoom and wide), I've tried the following code with no success :

```swift
camera?.setFlatMode(DJIFlatCameraMode.photoInterval, withCompletion: { (e:Error?) in
  // error handling...
  camera?.setPhotoTimeIntervalSettings(DJICameraPhotoTimeIntervalSettings.init(captureCount: 2, timeIntervalInSeconds: 5), withCompletion: { (e:Error?) in
    // error handling...

   camera?.setCameraVideoStreamSource(DJICameraVideoStreamSource.zoom, withCompletion: { (e:Error?) in

     // take the photo
     camera?.startShootPhoto(completion: { (error:Error?) in
       // error handling         

     })
   })
  })
})
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you need to use DJICamera.setCaptureStreamSources. I tried with Mobile iOS SDK, and ObjC app, but the call just crashes. They added this to the new version 4.14-trial1, but I couldn't make it work either.

https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-api/Components/Camera/DJICamera.html?search=djicamera&i=0&#djicamera_multilenses_setcapturecamerastreamsettings_inline

Answer (score 0):

```
DJICameraPhotoTimeIntervalSettings settings;
                    settings.captureCount = 2;
                    settings.timeIntervalInSeconds = 2;
                    
                    [weakCamera setPhotoTimeIntervalSettings:settings withCompletion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
                        if(error){
                            [ZQLog bLogE:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"camera settings error:%@", error.localizedDescription]];
                        }
                    }];
```

In my tests, i meet your error as:DJI SDK has come across unknown error code(217)  only once. In other tests, they run OK! And got images success.

Unfortunately, when sets to DJIFlatCameraModePhotoSingle, get no error with on image, same as you.